# Form closing when gecko browser shows popup

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I'm using `GeckoFx-Windows-22.0-0.7` and when I *click* something a popup with yes and no options is shown. My form closes without triggering `FormClosing` or `FormClosed` event. How can I solve this ?

It closes always before 3. popup.

I solved, Adding this code `GeckoWebBrowser.UseCustomPrompt();` before `Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize` is solved my problem.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell what it shows in popup ? and where you clicking ? show your valid code

Comment: @xpertgun Dou you want to delete this item(yes/no) ? or Do you want to copy images too . It doesnt matter what it show it closes always at 3. popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code  `GeckoWebBrowser.UseCustomPrompt();` before 
            `Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize` is solved my problem.

Comment: Hello Alper, you can accept your own question if no more assistance is required and the problem is solved

Comment: @Zefnus It says "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"